# Error: no matching function for call to ‘Order::Order()’

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



class Customer
{
    public :
    
    string email, name, address;
    long telephoneNo;
    
    int addNew()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the email, name, address and telephone no. of the user Please.\n";
        cin>>email>>name>>address>>telephoneNo;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int edit()
    {
        cout<<"Enter new name, email, address and telephone no. of user Please.\n";
        cin>>email>>name>>address>>telephoneNo;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int update()
    {
        cout<<"Enter new email, address and telephone no. of user Mr./Ms. "<<name<<" Please.\n";
        cin>>email>>address>>telephoneNo;
        return 0;
    }
    
};


class Order : public Customer
{
    public :
    
    static int number;
    const float price = 10000.0;
    float payment;
    string state, billingAddress;
    bool created, paymentMade;
    Customer *customer;
    
    Order(Customer *customer)
    {
        number++;
        this->customer = customer;
        payment = price + (0.1f*price);
        state = "West Bengal";
        billingAddress = customer->address;
        created = true;
        paymentMade = false;
    }
    
    int setState(string state)
    {
        this->state = state;
        return 0;
    }
    
    float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    
};
int Order::number = 0;

class Passenger : public Order
{
    public :
    
    string name;
    bool insurance, priorityBoarding;
    float luggage, extraLuggage;
    Order *order;
    
    Passenger(Order *order)
    {
        char flag;
        this->order = order;
        name = order->customer->name;
        cout<<"Enter the luggage amount for the customer Mr./Ms. "<<name<<", in kgs Please.\n";
        cin>>luggage;
        if(luggage > 15.0)
            extraLuggage = luggage - 15.0f;
        cout<<"Is the customer eligible for insurance. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            insurance = true;
        else
            insurance = false;
        cout<<"Is the customer a priority boarder. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            priorityBoarding = true;
        else
            priorityBoarding = false;
    }
    
    Passenger get()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    
    int edit()
    {
        char flag;
        cout<<"Please re-enter the name of the Passenger.\n";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter the luggage amount for the customer Mr./Ms. "<<name<<", in kgs Please.\n";
        cin>>luggage;
        if(luggage > 15.0)
            extraLuggage = luggage - 15.0f;
        cout<<"Is the customer eligible for insurance. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            insurance = true;
        else
            insurance = false;
        cout<<"Is the customer a priority boarder. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            priorityBoarding = true;
        else
            priorityBoarding = false;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int update()
    {
        char flag;
        cout<<"Enter the luggage amount for the customer Mr./Ms. "<<name<<", in kgs Please.\n";
        cin>>luggage;
        if(luggage > 15.0)
            extraLuggage = luggage - 15.0f;
        cout<<"Is the customer eligible for insurance. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            insurance = true;
        else
            insurance = false;
        cout<<"Is the customer a priority boarder. y/n? \n";
        cin>>flag;
        if(flag == 'y')
            priorityBoarding = true;
        else
            priorityBoarding = false;
        return 0;
    }

};

class OrderFlight : public Order, public Passenger
{
    public :
    
    static int flights;
    Passenger* passenger;
    
    int addPassenger(Order *order)
    {
        Passenger* passenger = new Passenger(&order);
        this->passenger = passenger;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int removePassanger()
    {
        delete(&passenger);
        return 0;
    }
    
    /*
    float getPrice(Passenger *passenger)
    {
        Passenger* gPassenger = Passenger::get();
        
    }
    */
};
int OrderFlight::flights = 50;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Getting the error ---

> In constructor ‘Passenger::Passenger(Order*)’: main.cpp:84:5: error:
> no matching function for call to ‘Order::Order()’

I am trying to send a pointer of the object of class `Order` in the constructor of `Passenger`, but getting this error instead. Did the same thing while passing the object or Order in the `addPassenger()` method of the `OrderFlight` class but did not get any error. Please help.

Comment: "An order is a special kind of customer, which also has a customer. A passenger is a special kind of order, which also has an order. An "orderflight" is both an order and a passenger (which is also an order), which has a passenger." Do you see that this makes little sense?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`class Passenger : public Order` says that a `Passenger` *is an* `Order`.  That doesn't really make sense, and ultimately is the source of your error:

Part of constructing a `Passenger` involves constructing all of its base classes, which includes `Order`.  However, `Order` does not have a default constructor, and you do not use a [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor) to tell it how to construct the `Order` part of itself, so it doesn't know what to do.

I would rethink your inheritance hierarchy here.  Like what I mentioned above, `class Order : public Customer` doesn't make sense because it implies that `Order`s *are* `Customer`s.  `class OrderFlight : public Order, public Passenger` also doesn't make sense for the same reason.

Comment: Then can you please tell me how to inherit the class and use its objects in the following subclasses in the correct way.

Comment: Generally you should prefer composition over inheritance. Composition implies a *"has-a"* relationship instead of an *"is-a"* relationship.  In practice this means that your objects should generally own instances (or references to instances) of other objects.  And you are already doing this - for example, your `Order` class contains a `Customer*`, and your `Passenger` contains an `Order*`.  That's all you need.